# Find all items with less than 10 items in stock

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make this inventory program. In case 4 of my switch I am trying to find all items from my inventory text file that have less than 10 items in stock. So far I am only able to find the item with the single lowest number of items, when I need all items with less than 10. Any help is greatly appreciated. My first question on this site so I hope you are gentle with me haha. :)

```
case 4:
    int lowest = 10;

    for( int i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
        if( allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces() < allItems[lowest].getNumberOfPieces())
            lowest = i;
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe items that have less than 10 pieces in stock: " + allItems[lowest]);
    break;
```

Again, this is my first question and I apologize if it is not well asked.

Comment: Your program is designed to find the minimum in an array. The logic itself is wrong. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I am new to programming obviously. I was completely guessing lol. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding the minimum, which is not really what you want, you could output the inventory item as soon as you find it to be less than 10. This would also save you the hassle of making a data structure, unless you want to use the list later again.

```
for( int i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
    int pieces = allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces();
    if( pieces < 10)
        System.out.println(pieces); //or whatever you'd like to print related to this index..
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is not outputting anything when I try to run it. It made me initialize the variable pieces so now that is =0 and I added some text to the output. It just does not output anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Post an ideone link with the code. It'd help me understand the problem.

Comment: You did not add `int pieces = allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces();`. How do you expect the value of `pieces` to get updated inside the loop for each item in `allItems`?

Comment: I did not use it because I get an error because it is already defined in my main method. I get this exact error: variable pieces is already defined in method main(String[])

Comment: So do NOT declare it again, but you still need to initialize it.
`pieces = allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces();` like this. I suggest you got through the basics of Java before attempting to solve programs.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I am doing this for a class. He gave us these practice review problems to work on for the first week before we get into the new stuff.  I am still getting back into the swing of it which is why I was having so many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a *LIST* of items which are lower than 10, then you obviously need a data structure to store multiple items, instead of just one like your variable `lowest`. So you need something like this:

```
List<Item> lessThanTen = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
    if (allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces() < 10) {
        lessThanTen.add(allItems[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright thank you :) I was completely guessing. I am pretty new to programming yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
int lowest = 10;
List<Item> items = new List<Item>(); //Item is supertype of all items

for (int i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++)
{
    if (allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces() < lowest)
    {
        items.add(allItems[i];//populate list of items with less than 10
    }    
}

System.out.println("The items that have less than 10 pieces in stock: ");
for(Item item : items)
{
    System.out.println(item.name);
}
```

Comment: Please modify your print line to include all the data you saved in `items`.

Answer (score 0):

Single **int** variable **lowest** is not enough here to store multiple data. You need ARRAY LIST there.

```
List<Item> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
   if (allItems[i].getNumberOfPieces() < 10) {
    data.add(allItems[i]);
  }
 }
```